cv2 VideoWriter writes small file with no video. Frames come from mss screen capture
I am writing a python script to capture the screen to a video but the resulting video file is only 8k long and there is no video in it. My code looks fine to me and I can see the captured frames which are just what I expect but the video has nothing in it. Can anyone see what is wrong? I tried different FOURCC codes like MJPG and DIVX but nothing works.
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image


width = 1600
height = 1024
bounding_box = {'top': 180, 'left': 3400, 'width': width, 'height': height}

sct = mss()
video_folder = 'C:/Users/Michael/Videos/Captures'
video_name = "capture.avi"
num = 0
ext = '.avi'
videopathname = os.path.join(video_folder, video_name)
video = cv2.VideoWriter(videopathname, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 24, (int(width),int(height)))
if video.isOpened():
    print('Opened Video File')
iFrame = 1
capturing = True

while capturing:
    sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)
    cv2.imshow('Capture', np.array(sct_img))
    iFrame += 1
    video.write(np.array(sct_img))
    print(iFrame, end='\n')
    if iFrame == 100:
        iFrame += 1

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        capturing = False

print("Finished!")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
print(videopathname + ' written and closed')


Make sure your application has access to the opencv_ffmpg dll file. Also check whether sct_img has resolution 1600 x 1024 which doesnt look like a common image resolution. Or use resize to force it to the writer resolution.

if you use VideoWriter(1600, 1024) then you have to write images with size (1600, 1024) because VideoWriter doesn't change size and it skips images which have wrong size. So you need something similar to sct_img = sct_img.resize(1600, 1024)

if you use VideoWriter(..., 24) to have 24 Frames Per Second then you have to write screenshot every ~41.66 milliseconds (1000/24 milliseconds) because VideoWriter doesn't control it  - it only keeps 24 as information for video player how fast to display frames. If you will write image every  ie. ~20 milliseconds (which gives ~50 Frames Per Second) then later player will display it in slow motion. If you will write every i.e ~80 milliseconds (which gives ~12 Frames Per Second) then later player will display it in fast motion.

@Micka I have no idea if my application has access to the opencv_ffmpg dll file. How can I check. I am using PyCharm

if the isOpened() works, and there are no warnings from opencv or ffmpeg, then you can assume that there are no DLL issues.

I found the problem. mss returns a RGBA image and VideoWriter needs an RGB image so the solution was to drop the A channel.     frame = frame[:, :, 0:3]

@MichaelMcLaughlin Maybe post that working solution as an Answer? It could help a future reader with same problem as written in the title.

I found the problem. The mss library screen grab routine returns an RGBA image, i.e. it has an alpha channel in addition to the RGB but the VideoWriter needs an RGB image as it's input so the solution was to drop the A channel like this:
frame = frame[:, :, 0:3]

I have been running through hoops to fix this problem. Took me forever to stumble on this answer, which worked immediately. In my case grabbing frames with 'picam2.capture_array()' and using 'cv2.VideoWriter'
